# How to change the orientation of the iDevice (iPad/iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator, uiinterfaceorientation, uidevice

It is easy to change orientation of the iPad/iPhone simulators by following: hardware->rotate left or right.
But, how can I change it on iDevice (iPad device or iPhone device?)

please can somebody help me?

should I add some code?
[image]

Comment: Can you explain your question? As far as i understood if you want to change orientation of your real device, i guess you must have to rotate your device with your hand. :D

Comment: look, I am running my application on iPad device, it appears as landscape mode, but I want it to appear with portrait mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to you summary tab, scroll down the to go "iPad Deployment Info".
Unselect all the four options in "Supported Interface Orientations".
Then select again, but select Portrait first and remaining after.

[image]

Also in View that you are expecting to be in portrait mode, just add

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    return (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the .plist file in Supporting Files

There you will see Supported interface orientations
Add below keys

```
Item 0 String Portrait (top home button)
Item 1 String Portrait (bottom home button)
Item 2 String Landscape (left home button)
Item 3 String Landscape (right home button)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

a call to UIApplication's `setStatusBarOrientation` will fake a rotation

Answer (score 0):

Add `Initial interface orientation` key/value to your `$appName-info.plist` file

[image: app-info.plist]